# How can I check if three elements already exist together in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a trick one that I just can't solve. I have a form that consists of address, day and time.

I need to check if the day and time have already been assigned to another address. And, if so, it doesn't add it to the table.

I've been thinking about this one. But I just can't figure it out.

Code Follows:

```
$('#diahora').click(function(event){ 
        //...var declarations...//

    var novoTotal = $("<tr>").append("<th class='endereco-usado'>" + addEnd + "<th class='dia-usado'>" + novoDia + "<th class='hora-usada'>" + novaHora).append("<th>" + "<a class='btn-xs btn-danger btn delHora'>Deletar</a>").append("<input class='horashidden flex-direction-nav'>").val(addEnd + ' ' + novoDia + ' ' + novaHora);

    var outroTotal = $("<tr>").append("<th>" + addEnd + "<th>" + novoDia + "<th>" + novoOutros1 + ' - ' + novoOutros2).append("<th>" + "<a class='btn-xs btn-danger btn delHora'>Deletar</a>").append("<input class='horashidden flex-direction-nav'>").val(addEnd + ' ' + novoDia + ' ' + novoOutros1 + ' - ' + novoOutros2);

    if(horaSelecao.val()== 'outros'){
        $('.diasehoras tbody').append(outroTotal);
    }else if($('.diasehoras tbody').text().indexOf(novoTotal.text()) !== -1){
        return alert('Dia e hora já selecionados.');
    }else{
        $('.diasehoras tbody').append(novoTotal);
    }
});
```

So, I already have a system that identifies if the complete set of the address exists in the DOM. But now, I need to check that above statement....

What is the best to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

you can store them in a map of some sort (i think this will work but i'm on my phone and it's been a long day):

```
var map = {};

if (map.hasOwnProperty(some_id)) {
    // already in the map
} else { 
    // added it to the map as a key/value pair
    // alternately use 'dot' notation, i.e., map.some_id = value
    map["some_id"] = your_unique_string_here;
}
```